# What is best dojo learning material?

Tags: dojo

I just want to know what is best learning tools for learning dojo for beginner.
Also is there any video tutorials for the same.

Comment: As of version 1.10, the [Dojo documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) has a lot of nice tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Download the code, demo and docs from http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.0/ and put it in a folder in your document root.
In the folder there must be the following folders

```
dijit/
dojo/
dojox/
util/
```

Open the test file in a webbrowser

```
http://localhost/dojo-release-1.10.0-src/dijit/tests/layout/test_SplitContainer.html
```

Open the file in your favorite text editor change the code and see the result.
The test files are the main resource to learn dojo.

The util folder contains some useful scripts for combining the dojo files and minifying it. This is not that useful as beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to learn dojo is to try is out yourself. I would recommend following books though:

1. Dojo: The Definitive Guide
2. Mastering Dojo (From Pragmatic Bookshelf)

Comment: Unfortunately, Dojo change radically in 1.7.  These books are no longer useful :(

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/

These are the largest collection of tutorials that I know of, and cover newer features that the books don't (though the books mentioned are invaluable). You may know about them already as pretty much any Google search for Dojo turns them up.

Also the Dojo IRC is helpful and friendly for specific question.